# Looking for a convenient way to import the frequently-used components in component?

Tags: vue.js

Is there a convenient way to import the frequently-used components?

When I write the components, if it need import other components, I will import and register them one by one:

```
import MyButton from './myButton'
import MyInput from './myInput'
import MyIcon from './myIcon'


export default {
  components: {
    MyButton,
    MyInput,
    MyIcon
  }
}
```

whether there is a simple way to import them?

Answer (score 1):

You just need use the webpack function to create a context, then import automatically.

create a `common_components.js` file in the `components` directory:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
}

// find all the *.vue under the `components` directory
const requireComponent = require.context(
  '.', false, /\.vue$/
)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  const componentName = capitalizeFirstLetter(
    fileName.replace(/^\.\//, '').replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
  )

  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
})
```

then in the `main.js` import the `common_components.js`, you can use all the components under the `components` directory now.

Comment: You can find more cool patterns like this one and more to use in vuejs here: https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k